# Why "markdown.styles": [] setting disappeared in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I could not find this setting by searching for "markdown styles" in the Settings page.
[image]

I am wondering if I lost the VS Code built-in markdown extension. Please see the image below, which shows what my search should've returned.

[image]

When I tried to add this setting to the settings.json file (another way to set the markdown style), "Unknown Configuration Setting" showed up as I hovered on it.

Unknown Configuration Setting:
[image]

I have tried resetting the settings.json file, reinstalled any relevant markdown extensions and even reinstalled VS Code, but it is still not working.

Comment: Please Provide Image what exactly the error

refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Click on the `Extensions` icon in the Side Bar (where the Explorer icon also lives).  In the search input box at the top, input `@builtin` and scroll down the results to see if the `Markdown Language Features` extension is listed. It should be, but maybe it got disabled.  Click on the little Gear icon on the `Markdown Language Features` extension entry to enable it if necessary.

Comment: @Mark: It works! Thank you Mark. You saved the day!

Comment: @HarshKairamkonda: Thanks for kindly reminding me of this.